# Функции контроллера домена

Tags: windows, домен, контроллер-домена

Давно мучает вопрос. А что же все таки из себя представляет контроллер домена? Active Directory? Да но не только же это, все же там есть набор других средств администрирования.
Так все же что еще может контроллер кроме как быть сервером AD? И зачем оно надо?

Поднимаю вопрос т.к. все еще интересует тема вопроса.

Comment: Да, интересно бы увидеть краткий и толковый перечень его функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер аутентификации Kerberos, сервер LDAP
Зачем надо? Если есть керберизованные приложения/сервисы можно использовать и как сервер аутентификации; LDAP - у меня, например, почтовый сервер postfix/cyrus-imap, адресную книгу получаю из AD скриптами на локальные машины. Кстати и централизованная аутентификация через Kerberos.

Comment: А LDAP авторизация безопасна?

Comment: Если через SSL, то да. Боишься хакеров в локальной сети?

Comment: Да) Хочется чтобы безопасность была на уровне)